# How to insert json array to mongodb using node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem when I try to save my json array to mongodb I am not show anythink,
**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sirketler')

var Company = require('./app/models/company');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var newCompany = Company({
      json:"sirketler" [
            {"Cityname":"Adana",
      "OSBname":"4 K PLASTİK AMB.TURZ.TAŞ.PET.ÜRÜN.DAY.TÜK.MAL.TEKS.GIDA VE TAR.ÜRÜN.İNŞ.İTH.İHR.SAN.TİC.LTD.ŞTİ.", 
      "Address":"A.H.S. ORGANİZE SANAYİ BÖLGESİ OSB LOKMAN HEKİM CADDESİ NO:2 ", 
      "Phone":123123123,
      "Fax":234234234,
      "Sector":"KAUÇUK VE PLASTİK ÜRÜNLERİN İMALATI ",   
      "Email":"gokhan@4kplastik.com", "Website":"www.4kplastik.com"},
     {"Cityname":"Ankara", "OSBname":"ABDİOĞULLARI PLASTİK VE AMB.SAN. A.Ş.",
     "OSBname":"ABDİOĞULLARI PLASTİK VE AMB.SAN. A.Ş.",
     "Address":"A.H.S. ORGANİZE SANAYİ BÖLGESİ OSB SABANCI CADDESİ NO: 8 ",
     "Phone":432143123,
     "Fax":243243243,
     "Sector":"KAUÇUK VE PLASTİK ÜRÜNLERİN İMALATI ",
     "Email":"info@abco.com.tr",
     "Website":"www.abco.com.tr"}

]});


    // save the user
    newCompany.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('User created!');
    });
})
app.listen (3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

**company.js** from /home/furkan/companies/app/models/company.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var companySchema = new Schema({

  Cityname: String,
  OSBname: { type: String},
  Address:{ type: String},
  Phone:{ type:Number},
  Fax:{ type:Number},
  Sector: { type: String},
  Email: {type: String},
  Website: { type: String},
  location: Number,
  meta: {
    age: Number,
    website: String
  },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var Company = mongoose.model('furkan', companySchema);

// make this available to our companys in our Node applications
module.exports = Company;
```

I look [image: this;]
sorry for my ask question style, I dont know how to ask clearly but my problem is this, please help me on this question.
I tried to add my code here but cod is not looks good.

*How can I do changes about my schema?

Comment: Post your code here. Also include your schema. One day, somebody will come to your question and would like to see what code you used. That link may not be up forever.

Comment: You need to create an object that matches the schema. Please show the schema so we can help.

Comment: I edited my post can you look this

Comment: You are not following the structure of your schema, follow the schema you made for company and it must be fine.

Comment: okay thanks, I am looking my schema now, I am trying to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema does not have a `json` field, nor `sirketler`.

When you use a schema, you must follow its structure.

You want something like

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var newCompany = Company({
        Cityname: "Adana", 
        OSBname: "4 K PLASTİK AMB.TURZ.TAŞ.PET.ÜRÜN.DAY.TÜK.MAL.TEKS.GIDA VE TAR.ÜRÜN.İNŞ.İTH.İHR.SAN.TİC.LTD.ŞTİ.", 
        Address: "A.H.S. ORGANİZE SANAYİ BÖLGESİ OSB LOKMAN HEKİM CADDESİ NO:2 ", 
        Phone: 123123123,
        Fax: 234234234,
        Sector: "KAUÇUK VE PLASTİK ÜRÜNLERİN İMALATI ", 
        Email: "gokhan@4kplastik.com", 
        Website: "www.4kplastik.com"
    });

    // save the user
    newCompany.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('User created!');
    });
})
```

**EDIT**

Just use [Model.create](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create). But again each company has to follow the structure specified in the schema.

```
Company.create([
    // company 1
    {
        Cityname: "Adana",
        OSBname: "4 K PLASTİK AMB.TURZ.TAŞ.PET.ÜRÜN.DAY.TÜK.MAL.TEKS.GIDA VE TAR.ÜRÜN.İNŞ.İTH.İHR.SAN.TİC.LTD.ŞTİ.", 
        Address: "A.H.S. ORGANİZE SANAYİ BÖLGESİ OSB LOKMAN HEKİM CADDESİ NO:2 ", 
        Phone: 123123123,
        Fax: 234234234,
        Sector: "KAUÇUK VE PLASTİK ÜRÜNLERİN İMALATI ",
        Email: "gokhan@4kplastik.com", 
        Website: "www.4kplastik.com"
    },
    // company 2
    {
        Cityname: "Ankara", 
        OSBname: "ABDİOĞULLARI PLASTİK VE AMB.SAN. A.Ş.",
        OSBname: "ABDİOĞULLARI PLASTİK VE AMB.SAN. A.Ş.",
        Address: "A.H.S. ORGANİZE SANAYİ BÖLGESİ OSB SABANCI CADDESİ NO: 8 ",
        Phone: 432143123,
        Fax: 243243243,
        Sector: "KAUÇUK VE PLASTİK ÜRÜNLERİN İMALATI ",
        Email: "info@abco.com.tr",
        Website: "www.abco.com.tr"
    }
], function (err, companies) {
    // ...
});
```

If you have an object where this data is stored, you would simply do

```
Company.create(obj.json.sirketler, function (err, companies) {
    // ...
})
```

If you want to save `json` or `sirketler` fields, you need to change your schema. You may need to set [strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) to `false`.

Comment: yes you are right thank you but I will add lots of company one is this and I will add more company information like this. How can I add json schema and how can I do that?

Comment: @FurkanKesgin I didn't quite understand your question. If you are trying to add multiple companies with one array, you could use [Model.create](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) but again each company in your array has to follow the structure (see example).

Comment: I edited my post I want to do, if I run this app mongodb show 2 value because there need to 2 information. one is adana one is ankara, but in same code also I will add istaanbul information under ankara. My problem is how can I add my those info with using json array mongodb.

Comment: Mikey, do you have a skype or other network? I will explain you what I want to do. my skype is : furkan_bfk